# Workbench section PHP assignment

Tags: 7, users, workbench

I have problem similar to [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14532/how-to-assign-a-section-to-a-specific-node-with-workbench).

I want assign node to section while being created. During php node creation I use:

```
    $node->workbench_access=array('1067');
```

which should assign node to certain section, but after script execution I see "Section: Unassigned".

When I do separately:

```
$node = node_load(823);
$node->workbench_access=array('1067');
node_save($node);
```

..it works. Section gets assigned. As I read Workbench access there might be some bugs preventing this from working (comments like "// Workbench Moderation submits the node twice???" and deleting of redundant nodes?)..

If it was matter of 1 node I would drop it and use second code.. But it seems like I need hundrets of nodes to be created at once so I'd rather avoid loading and saving node only for section assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with my own function that refreshes possible sections. So after I create item in menu - a lot of items - then i just run this, and new sections are available:

```
function update_workbench_sections($menu_name="example1") {

$wanted = array();
$records = db_query("SELECT mlid FROM {menu_links} WHERE menu_name=:menu_name", 
                        array( "menu_name"=>$menu_name))->fetchAll();

foreach($records as $w) {
    array_push($wanted, $w->mlid);  
}

$access_scheme = db_query("SELECT * FROM {workbench_access}")->fetchAll();
$existing = array();
foreach($access_scheme as $item) {
    if( intval($item->access_id)>0 && $item->access_type_id==$menu_name ) {
        array_push($existing, $item->access_id);        
    }
}

$missing = array_diff($wanted, $existing);
$values_to_insert = array();

foreach($missing as $item) {
    array_push($values_to_insert, array( "access_id" => $item, "access_type" => "menu", "access_scheme" => "menu",
                "access_type_id" => $menu_name ));  
}

if(count($values_to_insert)>0) {
    $query = db_insert("workbench_access")->fields( array('access_id', 'access_type', 'access_scheme', 'access_type_id'));
    foreach($values_to_insert as $value) {
        $query->values($value); 
    }
    $query->execute();
}
workbench_access_reset_tree();
module_invoke_all('workbench_access_save'); 
return count($values_to_insert);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you doing the call to workbench? Have you tried doing the call in the postprocess of the node creation. Maybe you don't have the proper database object yet when you do it?

Comment: I don't call workbench function. During node creation I just want to fill the field "workbench_access" to proper node id. Do you think the node needs to be created first and then modified (assigned to section) ? That's strange, as every field can be modified during node creation, before submitting...

Comment: ok, my error. I think what is happening is that your variable is not being written. First you have to check how other variables are written, if you had this in a form the variable value is normaly written somewhere like   node->variable['#value'][0]['und'] = 'value'; If this is not the case you should check where you are making this call. Sometimes you are filling the variables under form and not form_state which might be the problem or you are simply doing this before the variables that are to be written are placed. What is your wrapping function there?

Comment: I'm successfully writing other fields of node, so this one shouldn't be problem neither. Moreover when I separately load and save any node, this way of changing section works. Then I don't believe that problem lies in what you say.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would give away how and in which function you are setting that variable.

Comment: I have written a module, which I use to remote node creation. So after function that creates node, I just use the 3 lines I pasted before. This must be done after node save. Otherwise as I stated (reason of this topic) it won't work. Should I tell you more?

Comment: Could you paste the function that creates the node? That is what I don't get. If you are creating the node, this node has to know it is part of a workbench access node. Normaly there should be a hook that is attached to node save, that saves your workbench value to the workbench access table. The question is why is this hook not being called. Probably because your content type is not set, or this type is not linked with workbench_access